# Dynamically populate Select options via API call in React Final Form

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-final-form

I am using `react-final-form` and `react-final-form-listeners`. The first field in my form is an employee search. When the user selects an employee, I need to call an API to retrieve all documents associated with that employee, and then populate a `Select` with the fetched document names.

```
<Form
  render={({
    handleSubmit, form, submitting, pristine,
  }) => (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
    <Paper>
        <div>
        <InputLabel>Employee</InputLabel>
        <Field
            name="employee"
            label="Employee"
            component={employeeSearchAdapter}
        />
        <OnChange name="employee">
          {(employee) => {
            if (employee.employeeId) {
              fetchDocs(`/docs?empPin=${employee.employeeId}`, 'get')
                .then(res => res.json())
                .then(data => setDocs(data))
                .catch((err) => {
                  console.log(err);
                });
            }
          }}
        </OnChange>
        </div>
        <div>
        <Field
            label="Documents"
            name="documents"
            component={Select}
        >
            {docs ? docs.map(doc => <MenuItem key={doc.docId} value={doc.docName}>{doc.docName}</MenuItem>) : <MenuItem key="default" value="default">Select an Employee</MenuItem>}
        </Field>
        </div>
    </Paper>
    </form>
    )}
  />
```

The problem is that calling `setDocs(data)` rerenders the whole form and all other fields are cleared of their selected values. I tried using `<FormSpy />` in a similar way, but faced the same issue. How can I load this data in without losing values already entered by the user?

Comment: i have the same issue 
did you find any solution ?

Answer (score 0):

If you can consider change to use [react-final-form-hooks](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-final-form-hooks)
then you can utilize `useEffect` hooks.

```
import { useForm } from "react-final-form-hooks";
...
const [ options, setOptions ] = useState([]);
const { form, handleSubmit, submitting } = useForm({
    onSubmit,
    mutators,
    initialValues,
    ...
});
useEffect(() => {
   // fetch and setOptions
}, [form.getState().values.column]);

...
return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        ...
    </form>
);
```